# pgfplots plotting inverse exponential not working?

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to plot a graph of 100*e^(-x/5) in LaTeX but for some reason it will only plot up to x=5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
xlabel=$\Delta V$,
ylabel={$\% payload$},
xmin = 0,
xmax = 10,
ymin = 0,
ymax = 100,
samples = 65
] 
\addplot [black, smooth]{100*exp(-x/5)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there any reason for this? How can I get around it?

Comment: `xmin` and `xmax` only influence up to where the axis is drawn. Simply add `domain=0:10` and it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xmin` and `xmax` keys only influence the renge that the axis is drawn in, here one needs to influence the `domain` of the function:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   xlabel=$\Delta V$,
            ylabel={\% payload},
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 10,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 100,
            samples = 100,
            domain=0:10,
        ] 
        \addplot [black, smooth] {100*exp(-x*0.2)}; 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]